# conflicts when defining DataView after installed @type/vis and vis

Tags: angular, vis.js

js and angular to display some graphs on my web page. I installed

```
npm install vis 
npm install @type/vis
```

but I found both has a function called DataView.
I want to use DataView of vis but It seems angular automatically find DataView of @type/vis.

My code is like this:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Network, DataSet, DataView} from 'vis';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']

})
export class TestComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('network', {static: false}) el: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('nodeFilterSelect', {static:false}) nodeFilter: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('edgesFilter', {static: false}) edgeFilter: ElementRef;
  private networkInstance: any;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const nodes_set = new DataSet<any>([
        { id: 1, label: 'Eric Cartman', age: 'kid', gender: 'male' },
        { id: 2, label: 'Stan Marsh', age: 'kid', gender: 'male' },
        { id: 3, label: 'Wendy Testaburger', age: 'kid', gender: 'female' },
        { id: 4, label: 'Mr Mackey', age: 'adult', gender: 'male' },
        { id: 5, label: 'Sharon Marsh', age: 'adult', gender: 'female' }
    ]);

    const edges_set = new DataSet<any>([
        { from: 1, to: 2, relation: 'friend', arrows: 'to, from', color: { color: 'red'} },
        { from: 1, to: 3, relation: 'friend', arrows: 'to, from', color: { color: 'red'} },
        { from: 2, to: 3, relation: 'friend', arrows: 'to, from', color: { color: 'red'} },
        { from: 5, to: 2, relation: 'parent', arrows: 'to', color: { color: 'green'} },
        { from: 4, to: 1, relation: 'teacher', arrows: 'to', color: { color: 'blue'} },
        { from: 4, to: 2, relation: 'teacher', arrows: 'to', color: { color: 'blue'} },
        { from: 4, to: 3, relation: 'teacher', arrows: 'to', color: { color: 'blue'} },
    ]);


    const nodesView = new DataView(nodes_set, {})
    const edgesView = new DataView(edges_set, {})



    const container = this.el.nativeElement;


     const data = { nodes: nodes_set, edges: edges_set };
 [![enter image description here][1]][1]
     this.networkInstance = new Network(container, data, {});

  }
}
```

you can see I import DataView from vis, but we I put my cursor on the DataView, it like this:

[image]

And the DataView in @type/vis is:

```
export class DataView<T extends DataItem | DataGroup> {
  length: number;
  constructor(items: T[]);
}
```

So seems angular find the DataView of @type/vis even if I import it from vis
How to solve this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>That's how types work. They make sure you make the correct code. The package inside `@types` adds type hinting for the `vis` package, which does not supply its own typings. To fix your error, you need to pass an array, not an object:</strike>

```
const nodesView = new DataView(nodes_set);
const edgesView = new DataView(edges_set);
```

I've dug a bit deeper into it, and realized that the package `vis` is deprecated and is no longer maintained. Also the `@types/vis` should not be used anymore, as the new project [`vis.js`](https://github.com/visjs/vis-data) provides its own typings. So to get going for you, you need to do:

```
npm r vis @types/vis
npm i vis-data
```

You will then have proper typings of the package. For instance the `DataView` constructor has the following typing:

```
constructor(data: DataInterface<Item, IdProp>, options?: DataViewOptions<Item, IdProp>);
```

So you can keep your code the same:

```
const nodesView = new DataView(nodes_set, {});
const edgesView = new DataView(edges_set, {});
```

Where the second parameter are `DataViewOptions` with the following typings:

```
export interface DataViewOptions<Item, IdProp extends string> {
  fieldId?: IdProp;
  filter?: (item: Item) => boolean;
}
```

As a side note, I see you are using angular, the vis package has its own wrapper for angular as well. Perhaps you can have a look at it if it fits for your project: https://github.com/visjs/ngx-vis

Comment: The error saying "Expected 1 arguments, but got 2". change to array are still not fixing it. You are right I need like <DataItem|DataGrouop>[]. but how to change it??

Comment: @HongliBu I've updated my answer. I'm sorry I didn't look into it further, as my initial answer was plain wrong